# In bookshelf.js, I don't understand how to retrieve attribute from targets in hasOne() relationship for my template

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have a task object, the belongs to a job object.  It is a belongsTo() relationship, but I'm using a hasOne() relationship because I just couldn't figure out belongsTo().

My models are:

```
var job = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'jobs',
    idAttribute: 'id'
});

var task = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tasks',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    job: function() {
        return this.hasOne(Job);
    },
    job_summary: function() {
        return this.job().fetch().get('summary');
    }
});
```

I've tried a few combinations of the .job_summary() function, but nothing seems to work.  When I create a task object, I just want to be able to get the job summary of the related task, like:

```
var task_jobsummary = task.job_summary();
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:  I actually have 2 hasOne() targets I need to get data for.

EDIT:  I think my problem is not understanding promises.  If I were doing this in PHP, I'd do something like:

```
$myvar = stdClass();
$myvar->somefield = $task->getSomefield();
$myvar->anotherfield = $task->getAnotherField();
$myvar->jobfield = $job->getSomeJobField();
// ... etc
```

I want to simple return values from a then() after a fetch().

EDIT: Here is my code from my router:

```
var route_task(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.username = 'debug_username';
    res.locals.userpic = '/img/tmpuserpic.png';

    new Model.Task().fetch({id: req.params.id, withRelated: ['job']})
    .then(function(task) {
        task.related('job').fetch().then(function(job) {
            res.locals.somefield = job.get('somefield');
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        res.render('task');
    })
}
```

The two vars before the Model are set, and my template sees them.  However, the template doesn't see the res.locals.somefield setting.

Comment: It seems I don't understand how this works asynchronously.

Comment: You may want to add that this question is bookshelf.js related in the title... this may help get experts to read the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little bit confused, you need to have the belongsTo where you have the key and the hasOne where basically it is pointed.

For example a post has many (but is equal in concept) comments and a comment belongs to a post.

In the model you just need to say what relationship are, when you want to retrive it (maybe in the controller) you need to do something like this

```
new Model({id:4})
  .fetchOne({withRelated: ['thing']})
  .then(function(model) {
       // retrive the relation
       var things = model.things(); // you already had the query done
  });
```

You need to elaborate this but with the concept in mind the documentation helps a lot

Comment: That's how I have it.  My "many" model belongs to a "one" target.  I can query and fetch it correctly, like you have in your example, but I need to transfer not only fields from the "many" model, but also fields from the target "one" model.  So, my challenge is getting fields from the model, and the target model, into an object that I can pass to my EJS template.

Comment: My relations are fine, and I can fetch the target models.  My problem is simply returning values from a then().  From what I can tell so far, .then() returns a promise, so I need to know how I can get the value out of that promise.  In your example, how could I return things out of that then() function?

Comment: Look at the bookends plugin, it can make it much easier for you

Comment: Answeri g you question you don't, you launch your res.someting from inside your then

Comment: that seems like what I want, to use res.locals.  I can't seem to set it within my then() call though.  I call res.locals.myfield = job.get('myfield'), but my EJS template doesn't see it.  When I console.log(job.get('myfield')), it displays fine.  Is it out of scope?

Comment: That's strange, try a console.log(typeof things) I'm using it in a project in this exact way with sails.js

Comment: Yeah, I can console.log the model and it looks good.  I even .get() inside console.log and it displays as expected.

Comment: Kinda strange... Can you post the entire code? (I will reply tomorrow, I'm kinda drunk right now lol)

Comment: You don't enter in the second (outer) then,try to call res() in the inner then

Comment: Well, that worked.  I need to learn async programming, clearly.  Coming from the PHP world, it is driving me insane, but once I get it, I know it will be easier.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: And, now I see you're right about getting the related target.  I wasn't pulling the one I thought I was.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: If you have any question about this please comment and I will read and answer

Comment: Thanks, but I got it figured out.  Your advice worked perfectly.